# How to get flask app accessible through ingress without setting rewrite-target

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster that is making use of an Ingress to forward on traffic to a frontend React app and a backend Flask app. My problem is that the React app only works if rewrite-target annotation is not set and the flask app only works if it is.

How can I get my flask app accessible without setting this value (commented out in below yaml).

Here is the Ingress controller:

```
metadata:
  name: thesis-ingress
  namespace: thesis
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - thesis
      secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: thesis.info
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend
              port:
                number: 3000
        - path: /backend
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: backend
              port:
                number: 5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't specify, but I'm guessing your capture group was to rewrite `/backend/(.+)` to `/$1`; on that assumption:

Be aware that annotations are per-Ingress, but all Ingress resources are unioned across the cluster to comprise the whole of the configuration. Thus, if you need one rewrite and one without, just create two Ingress resources

```yaml
metadata:
  name: thesis-frontend
  namespace: thesis
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - thesis
      secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: thesis.info
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend
              port:
                number: 3000
---
metadata:
  name: thesis-backend
  namespace: thesis
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - thesis
      secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: thesis.info
        - path: /backend/(.+)
          backend:
            service:
              name: backend
              port:
                number: 5000
```

Comment: Ok you are right! That is exactly what I needed. I thought didnt realise that two Ingress could work on the same Ingress!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, and that it was something simple. Please accept the answer to let others know that you don't need help with this question anymore